# Can't see post status drop down for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I have a custom post type called `Group` for that I have assigned all required capabilities to Admin. However, I am still not able to see `Status` (post status) dropdown on edit screen.

## Admin Capabilities

```
$admin->add_cap("delete_others_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("delete_{$group_cap}");
$admin->add_cap("delete_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("delete_private_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("delete_published_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("edit_others_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("edit_{$group_cap}");
$admin->add_cap("edit_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("edit_private_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("edit_published_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("publish_{$group_cap}s");
$admin->add_cap("read_{$group_cap}");
$admin->add_cap("read_private_{$group_cap}s");
```

## Register Post

```
public static function register_group_type()
{

    $cap_type = self::$cpt_group;
    $plural   = 'Groups';
    $single   = 'Group';

    $labels = [
        'add_new'            => esc_html__("Add New {$single}", 'group-shop'),
        'add_new_item'       => esc_html__("Add New {$single}", 'group-shop'),
        'all_items'          => esc_html__($plural, 'group-shop'),
        'edit_item'          => esc_html__("Edit {$single}", 'group-shop'),
        'menu_name'          => esc_html__($plural, 'group-shop'),
        'name'               => esc_html__($plural, 'group-shop'),
        'name_admin_bar'     => esc_html__($single, 'group-shop'),
        'new_item'           => esc_html__("New {$single}", 'group-shop'),
        'not_found'          => esc_html__("No {$plural} Found", 'group-shop'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__("No {$plural} Found in Trash", 'group-shop'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => esc_html__("Parent {$plural} :", 'group-shop'),
        'search_items'       => esc_html__("Search {$plural}", 'group-shop'),
        'singular_name'      => esc_html__($single, 'group-shop'),
        'view_item'          => esc_html__("View {$single}", 'group-shop'),
    ];

    $labels = apply_filters('group_shop_group_labels', $labels);

    $capabilities = [
        'delete_others_posts'    => "delete_others_{$cap_type}s",
        'delete_post'            => "delete_{$cap_type}",
        'delete_posts'           => "delete_{$cap_type}s",
        'delete_private_posts'   => "delete_private_{$cap_type}s",
        'delete_published_posts' => "delete_published_{$cap_type}s",
        'edit_others_posts'      => "edit_others_{$cap_type}s",
        'edit_post'              => "edit_{$cap_type}",
        'edit_posts'             => "edit_{$cap_type}s",
        'edit_private_posts'     => "edit_private_{$cap_type}s",
        'edit_published_posts'   => "edit_published_{$cap_type}s",
        'publish_posts'          => "publish_{$cap_type}s",
        'read_post'              => "read_{$cap_type}",
        'read_private_posts'     => "read_private_{$cap_type}s",
    ];

    $capabilities = apply_filters('group_shop_group_capabilities', $capabilities);

    $rules = [
        'ep_mask'    => EP_PERMALINK,
        'feeds'      => FALSE,
        'pages'      => TRUE,
        'slug'       => esc_html__(strtolower($plural), 'group-shop'),
        'with_front' => FALSE,
    ];

    $rules = apply_filters('group_shop_product_rules', $rules);

    $args = [
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __('Groups for the team', 'group-shop'),
        'public'             => TRUE,
        'publicly_queryable' => TRUE,
        'show_ui'            => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'       => TRUE,
        'show_in_nav_menu'   => TRUE,
        'show_in_rest'       => TRUE,
        'query_var'          => TRUE,
        'rewrite'            => $rules,
        'capability_type'    => [$cap_type, $cap_type . 's'],
        'capabilities'       => $capabilities,
        'has_archive'        => TRUE,
        'hierarchical'       => FALSE,
        'map_meta_cap'       => TRUE,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-cart',
        'menu_position'      => NULL,
        'show_in_admin_bar'  => TRUE,
        'supports'           => ['title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail'],
    ];

    $args = apply_filters('group_shop_product_register', $args);

    register_post_type(strtolower(self::$cpt_group), $args);

}
```

## Image Reference - Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one.

In the classic editor the post status can be changed in the *Publish* box. There'll be a small *Edit* link next to where it says "Status: Published".

In the block editor, the post status is determined by the date and visibility set in the *Status & Visibility* box, under the *Document Tab*, and can be set to Draft by clicking *Switch to Draft* in the toolbar along the top.

There's no dropdown with just a list of statuses in either editor.

Comment: There is one Status dropdown with Gutenberg editor. I have added an image to the question please have a look.

Comment: I don't see any such dropdown on any site I've got with the block editor. Based on the arrow styling it appears to be a meta box built for the classic editor. It's likely added with a plugin or your theme.